# Reading File in Name ListBox without Path

Tags: vb.net

I use Visual Studio 2022, and I made a little program that saves the data in a directory in .txt format, then loads it into a ListBox without Path, selecting a file, transfers it to a TextBox.

The upload code is composed as follows:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCarica.Click
    Dim dirpath As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath 'scelta della directory
    Dim cerca() As String
    cerca = Directory.GetFiles(dirpath)
    For Each x As String In cerca
        lsbNomi.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)) **'caricamento nella ListBox dei file senza Path solo Nome**
    Next        
End Sub
```

The ListBox code is composed as follows:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lsbNomi.Click
    Dim leggi As StreamReader
    If lsbNomi.Text = Nothing Then MessageBox.Show("Selezionare un File esistente!", "ATTENZIONE!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) : Exit Sub
    leggi = File.OpenText(lsbNomi.SelectedItem) **'Punto dell'ERRORE**
    While leggi.Peek <> -1
        txtDati.Text += leggi.ReadLine() + vbCrLf
    End While
    leggi.Close()
    Dim lineCount As Integer = txtDati.Lines.Count
    If lineCount > 28 Then
        txtDati.Enabled = True
    Else
        txtDati.Enabled = False
    End If
    lsbNomi.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

When I choose a file to view, I get this error:

ERROR:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The file 'C:DistancebinDebugfriend' was not found.'
```

Since I chose to display only the file name and not its path, I think that the system I adopted to read the file in the ListBox and transfer it to the TextBox does not work.
Let me start by saying that if I view the files with the path and the extension, it works fine, but I would like to use only the Name.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance
Maurizio

Comment: In **English**, please !

Comment: `lsbNomi.SelectedItem.ToString() & ".txt"`

Comment: Good evening, I solved the problem that appeared in the listbox that could not find the path of the files,
because I only wanted to see the name without Path. I changed the file read line like this:

leggi = opentext(dirpath & " " & lsbNomi.SelectedItem & ".txt")

so doing the error does not appear because the files are found in his right sheep even if not
is displayed together with the files themselves, cordially 
Maurizio